# Question regarding Ramdisk image

Tags: beagleboard, ramdisk

I have just started using 0xlab's android port. I have been
successfully able to create the file system and have been able to
flash it as well. However, I have 2 questions to ask:
1) How do I create a ramdisk image and what should be the bootargs
given at the uboot prompt for this.
(I tried using ramdisk.img created in out/target/beagleboard/ but then
the kernel just does not boot when I use it.
Can any one help me out with this ?
2) How do I make my module part of the file system image. I have my
own driver, which I want to install after kernel boot up. What is the
procedure to ensure this module is part of the android.ubi image?

Someone please help me out with this. I have to get my module up and
running but because I don't know how to make my module part of the
ramdisk image/android.ubi, I am not able to proceed further. I am
hopeful someone witll help me here.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The generated "ramdisk.img" is not required for booting.  Instead, you should obly care about Linux kernel image and android image (system.img).  Please check wiki pages carefully.

Also, you can describe your own prebuilt kernel modules in file "Android.mk".  Example: http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_apps_demo-apks/blobs/beagle-donut/Android.mk